# Помогите написать паттерн "%s, %s, %i %s"

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Парсю простую строку вроде:
"Петрозаводск, Заводская, 1953 раз"
Пишу регулярку:

```
let str = "Петрозаводск, Заводская, 1953 раз";
let pattern = /[а-яА-Я 0-9._%+-]+, [а-яА-яZ0-9-]+, [0-9]+ [а-яА-Я]+/igm;
console.dir(str.match(pattern));
```

Но у меня почему то выдается целая строка. А мне нужно отдельно разбить: "Петрозаводск", "Заводская", "1953", "раз". Не получается, ни через matchAll, никак (
Сейчас написал подобный паттерн:

```
/([а-яА-яa-zA-z]+\s)+([а-яА-яa-zA-z]+\s)+([а-яА-яa-zA-z]+\s)/igm
```

Но никак не могу подставить запятую с пробелом. Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Сделал такой, но парсит с запятыми )
([а-яА-яa-zA-z]+[, ]+\s)+([а-яА-яa-zA-z]+[, ]+\s)+([а-яА-яa-zA-z0-9]+\s)

Comment: [`(.+)\,\s+(.+)\,\s+(\d+)\,?\s+(.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/Su1jWC/3)

Comment: А вам не проще будет сделать `split()` по запятой с пробелом, а потом ещё последний элемент разделить по пробелу?

Comment: Я извиняюсь, а какой функцией сравнить, почему-то console.dir(str.match(/(.+)\,\s+(.+)\,\s+(\d+)\,?\s+(.+)/gm));
Выдает  Array(1) => "Петрозаводск, Заводская, 1953 раз"

Comment: Если каждая строка содержит только один комплект элементов, вам не нужен флаг `g`, к тому же он не  даст получить подгруппы в результате `match()`. Да и флаг `m` вам не нужен, раз вы не используете `^` и `$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с регуляркой попроще:

```js
let str = "Петрозаводск, Заводская, 1953 раз";

const elements = str.match(/(.+?), (.+?), (\d+) (.+)/);

console.log(elements);
```

Вариант без регулярок:

```js
let str = "Петрозаводск, Заводская, 1953 раз";

const [city, address, rest] = str.split(', ');
const [number, last] = rest.split(' ');

console.log(city);
console.log(address);
console.log(number);
console.log(last);
```

Comment: `.split` может принимать регулярку, в ней можно указать по чему делить, например: `.split(/,\s?|\s/)` или даже так `.split(/,?\s/)`

Comment: Да, но для этого случая показалось, что хватит простых строк. Поскольку в названия городов могут входить пробелы (да и в названия улиц, хоть у автора пробелов в этом месте вроде нет), мы всё равно не сможем задать такую регулярку, которая разделила бы всё за один заход, не разделяя названий городов. Можно, конечно, заморочиться с заглядыванием вокруг и опереться на числа перед пробелом, но это показалось хрупким и переусложнённым.

Comment: Да и улицы бывают с числами: 9 мая и т.п.